# Regex lookahead won't work in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I got a Regex with lookahead that works with Regexr.com but not when using it in a .NET application.

This is some example input data (please note that I only created row breaks for readability, the text is in fact just one long row, therefor the need for a regex).

```
26. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 1\r\n -100\r\n
20. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 2\r\n -90\r\n
15. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 3\r\n 200\r\n
9. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 4\r\n 50\r\n
4. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 5\r\n -200\r\n
25. JUL\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 5\r\n -200\r\n
```

With the following regexp:

```
(.+?)(?=(\\r\\n\d{1,2}[.] [A-Z]{3})|$)
```

, I was hoping to capture each row, wanting to delimiter them with "20. AUG" and so on. Since the delimiter should also be captured i use a look ahead.
Everything worked great on Regexr.com, se example here: http://regexr.com/39fd7

When doing this in .NET:

```
Regex.Matches(input, "(.+?)(?=(\r\n\\d{1,2}[.] [A-Z]{3})|$)")
```

I only get these results:

```
-100
-90
200
50
-200
-200
```

I have tried with various RegexOptions like multiline and a few others, but without result.

Any help or hints is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The expression you showed at that link is not the same as the expression you used in .NET. In particular, the sequence `\\r\\n\d` became `<CRLF>\d`, where `<CRLF>` is a literal carriage-return-line-feed in the string.

Comment: Why on earth is this downvoted?  It's adequately researched, states the problem adequately, and is clear and concise.  I don't know what else you think you need.

Comment: I'm not sure your edit is correct @280Z28. This is the exact code i used: Regex.Matches(text, "(.+?)(?=(\r\n\\d{1,2}[.] [A-Z]{3})|$)") Why is there a need to escape the \r\n ? I think i forgot a double \ before the d though..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Edit

Based on the comments, it is apparent that the original question is misleading. The problem stems from the following:

The original C# code uses a string literal containing the exact sequence of characters `\r\n`, such as the following:

```
string input = "Example\r\nText";
```

The contents of the string were then copied *unaltered* to the online regular expression tester, so the tests were run on the equivalent of the following:

```
string notActuallyTheInput = "Example\\r\\nText";
```

It is now clear that the question means that the `input` string literal is written on one line, but the input itself *does* span multiple lines. Therefore, the problem lies in the `(.+?)` section of the expression. As [Robin mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25750015/138304), the `.` character does not match newline characters by default. The desired behavior is that of the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option, as shown in the following sample program.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    private const string Input =
        "26. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 1\r\n -100\r\n" +
        "20. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 2\r\n -90\r\n" +
        "15. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 3\r\n 200\r\n" +
        "9. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 4\r\n 50\r\n" +
        "4. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 5\r\n -200\r\n" +
        "25. JUL\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 5\r\n -200\r\n";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pattern = @"(.+?)(?=(\r\n\d{1,2}[.] [A-Z]{3})|$)";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(Input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} Matches:", matches.Count);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}", match.Value.Replace("\r", "\\r").Replace("\n", "\\n"));

        // OUTPUT:
        //
        // 7 Matches:
        //   26. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 1\r\n -100
        //   \r\n20. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 2\r\n -90
        //   \r\n15. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 3\r\n 200
        //   \r\n9. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 4\r\n 50
        //   \r\n4. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 5\r\n -200
        //   \r\n25. JUL\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 5\r\n -200\r
        //   \n
    }
}
```

---

### Original Answer

The problem likely stems from an incorrect translation of the regular expression to a C# string literal.

The following expression:

```
(.+?)(?=(\\r\\n\d{1,2}[.] [A-Z]{3})|$)
```

Would be written as either of the following in a C# string literal:

```
"(.+?)(?=(\\\\r\\\\n\\d{1,2}[.] [A-Z]{3})|$)"

@"(.+?)(?=(\\r\\n\d{1,2}[.] [A-Z]{3})|$)"
```

Since the input does not contain any quote characters, the latter is certainly the easiest translation since it's an exact copy of the original expression.

#### Complete program to reproduce results

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    private const string Input =
        "26. AUG\\r\\n2014\\r\\n27.08 Testing 1\\r\\n -100\\r\\n" +
        "20. AUG\\r\\n2014\\r\\n27.08 Testing 2\\r\\n -90\\r\\n" +
        "15. AUG\\r\\n2014\\r\\n27.08 Testing 3\\r\\n 200\\r\\n" +
        "9. AUG\\r\\n2014\\r\\n27.08 Testing 4\\r\\n 50\\r\\n" +
        "4. AUG\\r\\n2014\\r\\n27.08 Testing 5\\r\\n -200\\r\\n" +
        "25. JUL\\r\\n2014\\r\\n27.08 Testing 5\\r\\n -200\\r\\n";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pattern = @"(.+?)(?=(\\r\\n\d{1,2}[.] [A-Z]{3})|$)";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(Input, pattern);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} Matches:", matches.Count);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}", match.Value);

        // OUTPUT:
        //
        // 6 Matches:
        //   26. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 1\r\n -100
        //   \r\n20. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 2\r\n -90
        //   \r\n15. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 3\r\n 200
        //   \r\n9. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 4\r\n 50
        //   \r\n4. AUG\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 5\r\n -200
        //   \r\n25. JUL\r\n2014\r\n27.08 Testing 5\r\n -200\r\n
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried both ways and it will only be one result, and that's the one coming from |$.

Comment: @280Z28 i dont think that the problem is with incorrect character escaping.He's regex seems to be correct

Comment: @Anirudha When the correct string is used, the C# output matches the exact output he requested.

Comment: @Andreas When `Input` is the input you used at that link, and `pattern` is the one from this answer, then `Regex.Matches(Input, pattern)` returns the same 6 values that you indicated were the desired result from that link.

Comment: Your program example works. But my string contains \r\n not \\r\\n. If I try to modify your example code into that and also the regex, it will give me the same result as before with just the numbers (-200, etc) in the result.

Comment: @280Z28 Thank you, I'm impressed of your analysis which is spot on what happened :) The Regex now works great after adding the Singleline. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The regex wildcard `.` doesn't match newlines by default.

Your string appears "one row" but contains newline characters (`\r\n`) that, once interpreted in the string literal, prevent the dot from matching everything you want.

It will try to match `26. AUG`, then `2014`... until `-100`, when the look ahead finally matches, hence your final result.

Use the dot-match-all flag:

```
(?s).+?(?=\\r\\n\d{1,2}[.] [A-Z]{3}|$)
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. Just gives one result which is actually the whole line.

Comment: Even though the exact Regex didn't work for me, you were correct about the "one row", thanks. And as 280Z28 answered, all I had to do was add the Singleline option.

Answer (score 0):

If your text has always the same format (by 4 columns, separated by literals `\r\n`) you can use this simple pattern:

```
string pattern = @"(?:[^\\]+\\r\\n){4}";
```

[example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A%5B%5E%5C%5C%5D%2B%5C%5Cr%5C%5Cn)%7B4%7D&i=26.%20AUG%5Cr%5Cn2014%5Cr%5Cn27.08%20Testing%201%5Cr%5Cn%20-100%5Cr%5Cn20.%20AUG%5Cr%5Cn2014%5Cr%5Cn27.08%20Testing%202%5Cr%5Cn%20-90%5Cr%5Cn15.%20AUG%5Cr%5Cn2014%5Cr%5Cn27.08%20Testing%203%5Cr%5Cn%20200%5Cr%5Cn9.%20AUG%5Cr%5Cn2014%5Cr%5Cn27.08%20Testing%204%5Cr%5Cn%2050%5Cr%5Cn4.%20AUG%5Cr%5Cn2014%5Cr%5Cn27.08%20Testing%205%5Cr%5Cn%20-200%5Cr%5Cn25.%20JUL%5Cr%5Cn2014%5Cr%5Cn27.08%20Testing%205%5Cr%5Cn%20-200%5Cr%5Cn)

Comment: Looks good and I think I could rely on that. But strangely enough, I can't get it to work in .NET. But I can see that it works with your example. In .NET i just do Regex.Matches(text, @"(?:[^\\]+\r\n){4}") . It just gives one result with all of the text as result. Ive tried with \\r\\n also.

Comment: @Andreas:The pattern you can see in my answer has the good number of slashes, no need to change it, use a simple copy/paste.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. See: http://pastebin.com/yrigAbSW After execution matches3 will have no results.

Comment: @Andreas: Naturaly it doesn't work, your original string doesn't have a verbatim format!